# How to sort dates and then retrieve the other related data of that date?

Tags: apex

I am making a post request, which returns results that look like this:

```
Hospital from date 01:07/25/2020;
Hospital to date 01:08/04/2020;
Hospital NPI 01:1245678;
Hospital from date 02:06/29/2020;
Hospital to date 02:07/16/2020;
Hospital NPI 02:1245678;
Hospital from date 03:06/04/2020;
Hospital to date 03:06/09/2020;
Hospital NPI 03:1245678;
SNF from date 01:07/16/2020;
SNF to date 01:07/25/2020;
SNF NPI 01:1245678;
SNF from date 02:06/09/2020;
SNF to date 02:06/28/2020;
SNF NPI 02:1245678;
SNF from date 03:06/01/2020;
SNF to date 03:06/04/2020;
SNF NPI 03:1245678;
SNF from date 04:05/29/2020;
SNF to date 04:05/31/2020;
SNF NPI 04:1245678;
```

The way this works is that each 3 lines are one "group". So Hospital from date01, hospital to date01, and hospital NPI01 all go together, and same with the set with 02, and the SNF as well. What I need to do is sort of of those "groups" in order of the "from date". Meaning, I need to take all of the "From Dates" from all of the above lines (Hospital and SNF all together), and sort them in order of dates.

I know that I can add all of the from dates to a list and sort that list. But where I am getting stuck is how do I keep the "to date" and the "NPI" together with the from date after I sort it.

How can I do this in apex?

Comment: is it possible for the endpoint to provide you a structure that is easier to consume? like XML? This looks like EDI data. Is there a documented spec, so that you can confidently parse this without fear that it'll change unexpectedly and break your parsing and your integration?

Comment: I wish- but they just return a long string in the form as above.. I am displaying the results on a VF page, so in my controller I parse out the response with a bunch of strings like string snfFromDate1 = jsonString.substringBetween('SNF from date 01:', ';');  I know that to accomplish this task at hand i can simply then do date snf1 = date.parse(snfFromDate1); and the equivalent for each field, add those dates to a list and sort the list. The part of stuck on is how to then get the to date and the NPI that go along with each value from that list in order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have this data in `Apex`, the first step would be to understand how the **[`Comparable`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)** interface works. Once you read up on that, define a model:

```
public class DateGroup
{
    final Date fromDate, toDate, npi;
    public DateGroup(Date fromDate, Date toDate, Date npi)
    {
        this.fromDate = fromDate;
        this.toDate = toDate;
        this.npi = npi;
    }
}
```

Now you have a structure which can store the data in a representation that makes sense. From there you just have to add the sorting method.

```
public class DateGroup extends Comparable
{
    public Integer compareTo(Object instance)
    {
        DateGroup that = (DateGroup)instance;
        if (this.fromDate == that.fromDate) return 0;
        return this.fromDate > that.fromDate() ? 1 : -1;
    }
}
```